# Dim LED over time in a even flow using Arduino

Tags: arduino, pwm

Im trying to figure out how to dim a led over time(time is defined by the user lets call it rampUp). Im using arduino with the adafruit breakout PWM-Servo-Driver (http://www.adafruit.com/products/815) with the library : https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-PWM-Servo-Driver-Library

this breakout has 4095 steps (0-4095) so now my problem:

I want to be able to take a variable ( int minutes) and send that to a method that will dim a LED from 0 to 4095 in a equal light intensity increase for the period minutes. I want the increase to be incremented by 1 each time it increases.

So how do I write the method without using delay() ?

```
void dimLights(int rampUp){
  // some code to regulate the increase of the third value in setPWM one step at a time over a period of rampUp(int in minutes)
  led.setPWM(0,0,4095);
}
```

the reason for not wanting to use delay() is because it will pause/stop the rest of the program.

Answer (score 0):

I actually implemented something close recently:

```
void loop() {
    /* ... */
    if (rampUp != 0)
        led.setPWM(0,0,rampUp);
}

void led_update() {
    // here you can prescale even more by using something like
    // if (++global_led_idx == limit) {
    //   global_led_idx = 0;
    ++rampUp;
}

void start() {
    TCCR1B |= _BV(WGM12);
    // set up timer with prescaler = FCPU/1024 = 16MHz/1024 ⇒ 60ms
    TCCR1B |= _BV(CS12) | _BV(CS10);
    TCCR1B &= ~_BV(CS11);

    // initialize counter
    OCR1A = 0x0000;

    // enable global interrupts
    sei();
    // enable overflow interrupt
    TIMSK1 |= _BV(OCIE1A);
}

void TAGByKO_LED::stop() {
    TIMSK1 &= ~_BV(OCIE1A);
    rampUp = 0;
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect, ISR_NOBLOCK) {
    led_update();    
}
```

then you can call `start()` to start the timer, or `stop()` to stop it. You can read more documentation about the registers I've been using here and the `ISR` statement. Beware that it's one of the most tricky things of AVRs to really *understand*, and even then you'll always need to have a cheatsheet or the datasheet close by.

You may also use @sr-richie's solution with timers, but do only setup variables in the `dimLights()` function, and call `led.setPWM()` only within the `loop()`.